# Cadenas con separador y fechas codificadas en hexadecimal

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo pasar un archivo de texto con caracteres codificados a caracteres entendibles para el usuario?

Por ejemplo, tengo un archivo con las siguientes cadenas:

```
adl@ma@f@b@7e4
nin@fe@f@b@7e4
adm@ma@f@b@7e4
```

Donde se muestra:

- `adl`: se tiene que imprimir `Adulto`.
- `@`: se imprime un espacio.
- `fe`/`ma`: género (`femenino` o `masculino`).
- Los demás caracteres corresponden a la fecha en hexadecimal, la cual debe imprimir en decimal.

Comment: quisiera ayudarte pero generalmente para codificar y decodificar usamos algún algoritmo conocido, y lo que me muestras no me suena a ninguno que haya visto, bas64, hexadecimal, DS, 3DS, etc, y hay algunos que no son decodificables como el sha256 (tomaría años pero tampoco huele a ese algoritmo) entonces creo que falta un poco de información, ojala puedas encontrar ayuda. Sí lo que buscas es crear el algoritmo para encontrar el patrón primero debes hacer eso, un trabajo matemático y luego secuencializarlo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, nos vendría bien ver lo que has probado para mejorar o corregir aquello que esté mal, así como el valor que debería obtenerse de esa cadena que compartes.

Comment: demustra tu interes y dinos como has pensado hacerlo o lo que has intentado

Comment: @Diego-1743, no deberías confundir: **primero** codificar con cifrar, **segundo** no confundas los algoritmos de cifrado (crypt) como [3DES](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) (y no 3DS, que es una videoconsola) que es reversible (una entrada genera una salida cifrada y ésta, a su vez, genera en el proceso inverso, descifrar, la entrada inicial) con funciones de picadillo (hash) como [SHA256](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) que no son reversibles (infinidad de cadenas podrían generar exactamente el mismo picadillo).  Claramente `7e4` es el año `2020` en hexadecimal.

Comment: @OscarGarcia 7e4!! gracias ni por acá de que podía ser xd aunque ahora que el chico ha editado la publicación como que se ve al final 7e4 y tampoco se que es 7e4. "efe" - o tal vez yo no le entendí su pregunta, gracias por ayudarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema puede dividirse en problemas más pequeños para resolverlo:

- Dividir una cadena en partes mediante el delimitador `@`.
- Convertir de hexadecimal a decimal.
- Mostrar un texto basado en una referencia corta.

**Dividir una cadena en partes mediante el delimitador `@`**

Para ello he desarrollado una función que obtiene datos de la cadena haciendo uso de [`std::istream::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) usando `'@'` como parámetro `char delim`.

**Convertir de hexadecimal a decimal**

Podemos hacer uso de [`std::stol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stol/) indicando en el tercer parámetro que la cadena está en base 16.

**Mostrar un texto basado en una referencia corta**

Podemos hacemos uso de mapas de asignaciones con [`std::map`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

---

Código final:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

std::vector<std::string> dividir(const std::string& cadena)
{
    std::vector<std::string> partes;
    std::string parte;
    std::stringstream ss(cadena);
    /* Obtenemos cada parte separada por "@" y la agregamos al resultado */
    while (std::getline(ss, parte, '@')) {
        partes.push_back(parte);
    }
    return partes;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> lineas {
        "adl@ma@f@b@7e4",
        "nin@fe@f@b@7e4",
        "adm@ma@f@b@7e4"
    };
    std::vector<std::string> partes;
    /* Creamos mapas de asignaciones de los textos reducidos a los expandidos */
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mapaDeGenero = {
        { "fe", "femenino" },
        { "ma", "masculino" }
    };
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mapaDeEdad = {
        { "adl", "Adulto" },
        { "nin", "Niño" },
        { "adm", "Administrador" }
    };

    /* Iteramos por cada cadena que deseamos analizar */
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < lineas.size(); i++) {
        /* Obtenemos las partes usando el delimitador @ */
        partes = dividir(lineas[i]);
        /* Mostramos los resultados tal y como se esperan */
        std::cout << mapaDeEdad[partes[0]] << " "
            << mapaDeGenero[partes[1]] << " "
            << std::stol(partes[2], nullptr, 16) << "/"
            << std::stol(partes[3], nullptr, 16) << "/"
            << std::stol(partes[4], nullptr, 16) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Resultado de la ejecución:

```
$ g++ -Wall --pedantic pr.cpp -o pr
$ ./pr
Adulto masculino 15/11/2020
Niño femenino 15/11/2020
Administrador masculino 15/11/2020
```

Puedes ver el resultado de la ejecución en línea en el siguiente enlace (recuerda seleccionar "None" en la columna "Standard Input" de la pestaña "Options"):

- http://cpp.sh/4smo3

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta perfecta al explicación.

Comment: De nada, un placer ser de ayuda. Si la respuesta solucionó tu duda no olvides marcarla como correcta para dar por cerrada la pregunta. Gracias.